# Balanced partition of iterator range without LegacyRandomAccessIterator

Tags: c++

Let's start with a simple example:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
... // fill it
auto begin = foo.begin();
auto end = foo.end();
auto middle = begin + std::distance(begin, end) / 2;
```

If the iterators have the `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` trait, ideal bi-partition of the iterator range is embarrassingly easy, and so is therefor any form of divide-and-conquer type algorithm. This pattern is commonly found in the STL implementations too.

If they provide only the `LegacyForwardIterator` trait, only thing we can do in constant time is:

```
std::set<int> foo;
... // fill it
auto begin = foo.begin();
auto end = foo.end();
auto middle = (begin != end) ? ++(begin) : begin;
```

No chance of processing the iterator range in an even remotely balanced way without a linear scan.

It's easy to understand that for most containers not providing `LegacyRandomAccessIterator`, an ideal partition scheme can't be for free. However, most containers would still be able to provide a partitioning scheme better than `1:n-1` on average at a constant cost.

Any container based on a self balancing tree would be trivially able to guarantee a worst-case ratio based on intrinsic implementation details. Any hash table - be it bucket or multiple round based - still has a high chance of providing a good partition, just by slicing the hash table itself in half.

Only imbalanced trees or plain lists are by design unsuitable.

This deficit also shows in STL internal algorithms depending on a somewhat balanced division, e.g. like `std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, ...)`. Even though most STL containers in about all implementations have implementation details which allow constant time partition into remotely balanced chunks, I have yet to see any STL implementation handling anything except `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` better than pure single element round-robin. Commonly resulting in false-sharing of cache lines, and synchronization overhead far beyond any practical value.

This begs the question, how come that the C++ language provides no interface to request a better partition scheme for any STL containers? Or is there one I am just not aware of?

Comment: Many of the containers implement their own version of the algorithms to take advantage of these facts

Comment: @NathanOliver You would expect so, but skimming through the implementations, that is not the case except for explicit member methods (like e.g. `std::set::find`) and explicit overloads like `swap` etc. At least MS STL / libcxx only distinguish based on iterator traits, nothing more. Correspondingly, neither performs any bisection without random access trait.

Comment: The algorithms all work with _iterators_, not _containers_. Even if you provide a way to get the "midpoint" iterator for an arbitrary container, the algorithms typically need to repeatedly subdivide intervals, which they won't be able to do without knowledge of the underlying container - something the algorithms do not have.

Comment: To improve the question, post code where the actual issue is seen. This is currently going towards a XY question.

Answer (score 1):

While this question makes sense in a vacuum, I couldn't find a container where it would matter.

1. All associate containers are already inherently sorted and already provides specialized accessors and api's.
2. We can ignore sequence containers that provide random access since we are not concerned with those.
3. That leaves just `std::list` and `std::forward_list`. Both do not have the layout neccesary for providing a balanced division.

So there is no container left where this issue pops up, at least not in the standard library. Unless, perhaps, you are talking about using eg. `std::lower_bound` with eg. a `std::map` (perhaps for some generic purpose) ?

---

Concerning the case `std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, ...)` working on a `std::set`:

This is specialized case.
There is choice even in this case and theres a tradeoff in performance (Remember that the `std::set` implementation are **strictly private** - there is not a guarentee that it is implemented with RB tree and therefore doesn't neccesarily know the median/precisely divisions). And without a precise division you could be worse off for a lot of use cases for processing, Im guessing. Therefore, you case/need is too specialized for the standard library as it stands and you should probably just implement a specialized `for_each` that handles you actual need. Or try to use a **sorted** `std::vector` instead (wrether you keep it sorted or sort it just when needed can make or break the performance), ie. if you don't have too many inserts in the middle and needs it sorted throughout - you could experiment with the `std::deque` as well.

**That being said, it is possible that this idea should be added into a new iterator concept in the future, but I guess no one really gave it any thought as of yet.**

Comment: `std::map` has a [`lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) function, too.

Comment: @Ivella indeed, and that should be used instead of the algorithm version. Therefore it was one of the only examples I could come up where the algorithm version of std::lower_bound where the OP would have an issue.

Comment: For me that actually popped up when trying to utilize parallel algorithms from C++17 for element-wise bulk processing, and it turned out to perform significantly worse for anything not random-access, due to the mentioned overhead from the lack of any divide-and-conquer friendly iteration scheme.

Comment: Real life example, I have a sparse `std::set` indexing elements of interest. The properties of a set are required for maintaining the index (unique, bounded update costs, sorted so index iteration yields cache locality in indexed memory). But the issue doesn't occur when using it as a set, instead it shows (as a performance deficit) when treating it as a generic collection with use of  `<algorithms>`, specifically when expecting a proper scaling with `std::execution::par_unseq` execution policy.

Comment: @Ext3h you mention `std::for_each` (with `std::execution::par_unseq` execution), but that (in itself at least) shouldn't need to divide, should it ? perhaps the issue you see is something else than what you think is the issue ?

Comment: @darune Actually is has to divide it in order to distribute the work. Without a proper division strategy, there are only two possible implementations, either each threads only processes each n-th element it has visited with a thread local iterator copy, or all threads use a synchronization primitive and share the same iterator. First option burns time on iteration, second suffers from contention. First has same lower bound as single-threaded no-op iteration, second even scales negatively with additional threads due to contention related issues.

Comment: @Ext3h If you are asking specifically about `std::execution::par_unseq`, that is easy: there was no thread before C++11, and no `std::execution::par_unseq` before C++17. Thus, the only point in time where such special semi-random iterator could have been introduced was at C++17, and you probably are one of the firsts to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses for the reason:

- Nobody thought about it, as the natural thing to do is implement the algorithm on the classes themselves (see darune's answer).
- An hypothetical *LegacyStochasticHalfWayIterator* would be too inelegant solution as an iterator, because iterators adhere to pointer arithmetic interface, and an interface to get the stochastic half way between two iterators certainly breaks this pointer abstraction.